# How to integrate DTM (Dynamic Tag Management) with AEM 6?

Tags: aem, adobe-analytics

I am a newbie to Adobe DTM (Dynamic Tag Management) and have not done any kind of training related to it. However, I have been given a requirement to integrate DTM with AEM 6. I Have some requirements related to Omniture where certain events on the website are tracked and that information needs to be sent to DTM. I have followed steps described on this blog (http://blogs.adobe.com/aemtutorials/2013/07/24/customize-the-client-context/) to customize the client context by creating a new session store and storing some sample data inside it. Now, next part is to retrieve this data into DTM which I am completely unaware on how to do. What is need to achieve in particular is to create a new data element as shown in the screenshot below and write some custom java script to access the data stored inside the client context (which is present in the session store) as explained in the blog mentioned.

[image]

I have no idea on how to integrate DTM with AEM instance and how to get hold of that data needed using the script. There is no info available on the internet regarding this, hence request you to help me in case anybody have worked on such a requirement earlier. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Set up DTM cloud services configuration in AEM. You may find cloud services config at /etc/cloudservices/dynamictagmanagement.html

Step 2 - Apply the above cloud config to the root of your website using the page property. This will insert the required JS scripts and JS object into the DOM. You could also do step (1) & (2) together by manually inserting header and footer code (from DTM) into the template.

Step 3 - Supply data to DTM JS object. This you could populate the data from server side or at client side using JS. You could leverage client context as well. JS APIs available to query client context.

PS: Am also a learner on this.

Helpful links:

http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/integrating-dtm-custom-aem6-page-template/

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/integration/marketing-cloud/dtm.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use data elements with custom script like this:
e.g. dataElement authorizableId is custom script with content
return CQ_Analytics.ClientContext.get("/profile/authorizableId");
or 
dataElement pageTitle 
return CQ_Analytics.PageDataMgr.getProperty("title”);

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it. Please note that this implementation is for integrating with flat HTML files. Where we need to add the scripts in Head tag.

Pre-requisites: 
1.  We need to have login credentials for DTM website.

2. We need to have admin rights.
3. We need sc3.omniture site credentials. This is usually provided by Adobe team.
4. From Omniture console we need to generate the AppMeasurement.js file.
5. From AppMeasurement.js file we need to get important details like:
   a.  Tracking Server Name
   b.  s_account name
   c.  Visitor namespace

Connecting HTML files to DTM:

1. Login to https://dtm.adobe.com with admin credentials.
2. Click on Project dashboard
3. Click on Embed tab on top navigation.
4. Enable Host on Akamai.
5. Expand Header Code widget and copy the code.
6. Paste that code in the  tag of your HTML.
7. Go back to DTM again. Expand Footer Code widget and copy the code.
8. Paste that code to the  tag of your HTML.

Configuring DTM for Direct Call Rules:
1.  Go to Rules tab from top navigation.
2.  Click on Direct Call Rules from left navigation now.

3. Click on create rule.
4. Give it a name in the Name section.
5. Expand Conditions widget.
6. Pay close attention to the Conditions textbox. Direct Call Rules are fired using the _satelitte.track() method, and the text you enter in the Conditions textbox will be the argument you pass in this method. We entered “change-offer-submit”, so to fire this Direct Call Rule, we will use _satelitte.track(“change-offer-submit”) as you will see in the code below.
7. Now use the Adobe Analytics section to set up a custom link.
8. Below is the code that sets up our form and its validation. Notice the way the DTM _satelitte.track() is used. Each of the arguments passed in the _satelitte.track() method matches the Condition textbox in separate DTM rules.

HTML

```
<div class="outer-btn">
                            <input class="input-btn analyticsEvent" type="button" value="Submit" data-eventName="change-offer-submit">
                        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>    
jQuery('.analyticsEvent').on('click',function() {    
    window.console.log('Logged Event: ' + jQuery(this).attr('data-eventName'));    
    _satellite.track(jQuery(this).attr('data-eventName'));    
     location.href='./landingPage.html';     
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been superseded by a tool added to DTM in the June 2016 release, ContextHub was added in 6.1 as beta, in 6.2 it reached feature parity with ClientContext. It saves a lot of time building data layers as a lot of it will be there already .